# VK_NULL_HANDLE is always 0; Why not nullptr?

Tags: c++, c, graphics, vulkan

In most cases, you can get away with assigning `VK_NULL_HANDLE` to any handle defined by `VK_DEFINE_HANDLE(object)` or `VK_DEFINE_NON_DISPATCHABLE_HANDLE(object)`, but `std::exchange()` fails to set this value in almost all cases.

In most situations I have to call `std::exchange(m_dispatchableHandle, nullptr)` and `std::exchange(m_nonDispatchableHandle, nullptr)`
However, on x86, nullptr is invalid due to the redefinition of `VK_DEFINE_NON_DISPATCHABLE_HANDLE`. I must use `std::exchange` with `NULL`, `0`, or (finally) `VK_NULL_HANDLE`.

My question: in following the `VK_DEFINE_HANDLE` macro patterns, should there not be two null handle macros defined like the following?

```
#define VK_NULL_HANDLE nullptr
#if defined(__LP64__) || defined(_WIN64) || (defined(__x86_64__) && !defined(__ILP32__) ) || defined(_M_X64) || defined(__ia64) || defined (_M_IA64) || defined(__aarch64__) || defined(__powerpc64__)
#define VK_NON_DISPATCHABLE_NULL_HANDLE nullptr
#else
#define VK_NON_DISPATCHABLE_NULL_HANDLE 0
#endif
```

If nothing else, it seems like `#define VK_NULL_HANDLE nullptr` would have more utility in general.

I may be misunderstanding how the API is supposed to be used, so I'm sharing the trouble code in question: a move constructor that transfers handles and fills the old object with `NULL` or `VK_NULL_HANDLE`. By carefully managing ownership, the class can be designed simply and handle `vkDestroy*` et. al. in its destructor.

```
class RenderContext
{
public:
    RenderContext(VkPhysicalDevice physicalDevice, uint32_t gfxQueueFamilyIdx, uint32_t presentQueueFamilyIdx);
    RenderContext(const RenderContext& other) = delete;
    RenderContext& operator=(const RenderContext& other) = delete;
    RenderContext(RenderContext&& other) noexcept;
    RenderContext&& operator=(RenderContext&& other) = delete;
    ~RenderContext();
private:
    VkDevice _device;
    VkCommandPool _gCmdPool;
    VkCommandPool _pCmdPool;
    VkQueue _gQueue;
    VkQueue _pQueue;
};

RenderContext::RenderContext(VkPhysicalDevice physicalDevice, uint32_t gfxQueueFamilyIdx, uint32_t presentQueueFamilyIdx) :
    _device(VK_NULL_HANDLE),
    _gCmdPool(VK_NULL_HANDLE),
    _pCmdPool(VK_NULL_HANDLE),
    _gQueue(VK_NULL_HANDLE),
    _pQueue(VK_NULL_HANDLE)
{
    // ...
}

RenderContext::RenderContext(RenderContext&& other) noexcept :
    _device(std::exchange(other._device, nullptr)),
    _gCmdPool(std::exchange(other._gCmdPool, VK_NULL_HANDLE)),
    _pCmdPool(std::exchange(other._pCmdPool, VK_NULL_HANDLE)),
    _gQueue(std::exchange(other._gQueue, nullptr)),
    _pQueue(std::exchange(other._pQueue, nullptr))
{}


RenderContext::~RenderContext()
{
    vkDestroyCommandPool(_device, _pCmdPool, nullptr);
    vkDestroyCommandPool(_device, _gCmdPool, nullptr);
    vkDestroyDevice(_device, nullptr);
}
```

Comment: Isn't that a C library? `nullptr` doesn't exist in C.

Comment: Doesn't that suggest, then, that there's no way in the C language to enforce some of the Vulkan spec? There are specific behaviours that establish that dispatchable handles can be VK_NULL_HANDLE and non-dispatchables can be NULL. If VK_NULL_HANDLE expands to an int, then both are effectively an int.

Comment: Vulkan definitely isn't my area, but `(void*)0` is how a null pointer constant would typically type confusion with `int`. Of course `0` still fits both, which isn't ideal when trying to separate the two.

Comment: @chris, `nullptr` is going to be added in C23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates in C++ require precise type, not just compatible one, to properly instantiate. As such C's `NULL` (defined as `0`) might be a problem. `0` might also be a problem as it is `int`, not `uint64_t`, which is the ABI of Non-dispatchable Handles (which can be stored in 64 bit pointer to get some type safety out of C). This is not new when dealing with C libraries from C++ (or generally).

Rest is design questions and suggestions adressed at authors, and as such unsuitable for StackOverflow. The issue tracking system is available at https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/issues. On the face, your suggestion makes sense to me. They probably do not want to make it pervasive, but additionally, it might be a case for doing `#ifdef __cplusplus #define VK_NULL_HANDLE nullptr`.

Alternatively, there is Vulkan-Hpp, which is supposed expose more C++-istic bindings to Vulkan.

Proper way currently to call the template function would be `std::exchange(m_nonDispatchableHandle, decltype(m_nonDispatchableHandle)(VK_NULL_HANDLE));`.

Comment: Thank you. I see that my question makes this more of a C/C++ question than Vulkan, but I will leave it up because your response is extremely useful to newbies looking for this technical information. Others may be coming at Vulkan with little C knowledge as I did.

Answer (score 0):

> In most cases, `VK_NULL_HANDLE` can be assigned to any handle defined by `VK_DEFINE_HANDLE(object)` or `VK_DEFINE_NON_DISPATCHABLE_HANDLE(object)`

Wrong. You can *get away with it* because C and C++ let you. But the Vulkan specification is very clear:

> The reserved values `VK_NULL_HANDLE` and `NULL` can be used in place of valid non-dispatchable handles and dispatchable handles, respectively

That is, `VK_NULL_HANDLE` is *only* for non-dispatchable handles. That the C/C++ languages allow you to assign the value of `VK_NULL_HANDLE` to a dispatchable handle is merely a function of the language, and the behavior for Vulkan itself is not defined.

You should never be trying to `std::exchange` between a dispatchable handle and a non-dispatchable handle, just as you should never be trying to `std::exchange` between two distinct types.

Comment: My question is still valid in the sense that VK_NULL_HANDLE is only actually typed correctly for non-dispatchable handles in certain situations on only some architectures, based on the pragma defs for VK_DEFINE_NON_DISPATCHABLE_HANDLE. On x64 architectures, etc, VK_NULL_HANDLE should probably be defined as `(void*)0` instead of just `0`.

Comment: @AaronHull: But non-dispatchable handles are not *pointers*; they're *integers*. If you do `(void*)0`, then it's a pointer, and C++ *will not* implicitly convert a pointer to an integer. It will however implicitly convert the integer literal zero to a (null) pointer, which is what allows you to pass `VK_NULL_HANDLE` to dispatchable handles.

Comment: @NicolBolas It's supposed to be implementation detail, but they are pointers on x64 to get some type safety to handles out of C.